# Multiple source shortest path...Embeded plannar graph

Tags: algorithm, shortest-path

The tree on which mssp(multiple source shortest path) can be executed, is stated in many papers that it must be an embeded plannar graph. Does this mean that there can be no edges that overlap each other? If so is possible[image] to change such graph into a plannar graph?

Comment: planar graphs allow for parallel edges. What do you mean by "overlap"?

Comment: meaning that no edge between two vertices can intersect with another edge.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The canonical input to MSSP is a [doubly connected edge list](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Doubly_connected_edge_list) or something like it that gives the combinatorial topology of the graph but not the geometry. If you have a [straight-line graph](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Planar_straight_line_graph) that's not planar (i.e., it has edges that cross or overlap), then you need to change the graph somehow. One possibility is to introduce a new vertex everywhere there's an intersection; another is to delete problematic edges.

Comment: something similar to a doubly connected edge list would be a top tree representation of the mst isnt it? giving details of the edges making part of the tree? am i correct? The graph that i have is like the above graph.

Comment: The DCEL represents the whole graph, so a data structure that stores only trees is not appropriate. There are variants of the DCEL that provide access to similar information (given a half-edge x, what is the half-edge in counterclockwise order with the same head, and what is the half-edge of opposite orientation?)